# Endeca range filters manual sort order

Tags: endeca

I am working on a **custom Endeca app** [MDEX 6.1.4], where there are no CAS record stores. There are csv and txt files containing data to be loaded. I am trying to sort my **range dimensions** in developer studio in the order I define their values (*in the Dimension Editor*), the Dev Studio saves the **DVAL_RANK** correctly, however the sort order in the Endeca JSPREF, doesn't appear as in the Dev studio for the dimension values.

Here's what I have tried already:

1. Clearing the state directory and changing the fcm.conflicts.xml to set the owner of the *dimension of interest* to DEV_STUDIO
2. Manually changing the ranks, however the dval_ranks file reaching the appName/data/processing/ directory has dval_rank = 1 for all the values in the range dimension.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding the DVAL_RANK element for the dimension Id in projectName.dval_ranks.xml

It is required for the dimension to have a rank specified in the pipeline, for the FCM to assign the ranks to the dimension values (*it's children*). When I added the dimension with a rank, it picked the correct ranks for the dimension values too.

Hope this helps someone!